# kafka-topics.sh --describe don't return anything

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running a kafka cluster composed by 3 nodes.
One of the nodes crashed and it has been behaving oddly since then...

The following does not return anything on the malfunctioning node:

```
kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper mynode01:2181
```

However, querying the topics on the other nodes return the expected topics.

Another thing I saw is that zookeeper seems to be missing some directories:

```
./zkCli.sh -server mynode01
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /
[controller, zookeeper]
```

Whereas if I check any other node it comes back with:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /
[isr_change_notification, zookeeper, admin, consumers, config, controller, brokers]
```

The logs report the following entry:

```
Error for partition [myqueue-1,0] to broker 1:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NotLeaderForPartitionException: This server is not the leader for that topic-partition. (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

I tried a couple of things already to sort this out, with no joy:

1. Restart the kafka cluster, so that other node becomes leader.
2. Assign a different leader for the topics affected by running ./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh
3. Stop kafka and zookeeper services on the affected node, remove kafka-logs and zkdata and start them back up.

Although the cluster seems to be able to treat this node as any other and switch the roles of leader/follower with no issues... it looks like it got out of sync at some point and is not able to recover itself.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by stopping zookeeper and kafka services in the affected node and removing the snapshots available in zkdata and the associated transaction logs available in zklog directories.

After starting zookeeper back up on the the affected node, the znodes missing were re-synced back.